# How can I mass rename files in Linux containing spaces?

Tags: linux

I want to rename all of the pdf files that contains spaces by replacing them by underscores.
So I invoke the command:

```
ls *.pdf | sed -e 'p; s/" "/_/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

and I got errors on the terminal:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘Beginning’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Linux’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Line.pdf’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Command’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Head’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘C.pdf’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘First’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Head’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘PHP’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘MySQL.pdf’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘First’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘and’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Linux’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Guide.pdf’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Pocket’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘C.pdf’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘ANSI’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Command’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Command’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Programming’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘The’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Programming’: No such file or directory
```

So what is wrong in the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the Perl-based `rename` command (sometimes called `prename`) to do the job:

```
prename 's/ /_/g' *.pdf
```

The shell globbing keeps each file name separate; the `prename` command does bulk renaming; the `s/ /_/g` operation replaces each blank by `_` everywhere in the file name. (The original code only replaces the first blank with an underscore, and then runs foul of `xargs` breaking on white space (blanks and tabs as well as newlines.)

Comment: very much my tool of the trade (also, lol @ duplicate :))

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `sed` command does not match any files because you are trying to match `quote-space-quote` instead of just a `space`. Unless you have a file literally named `A" "file.pdf`, you will not match it with `sed`.

Let's say you've fixed it to `sed -e 'p; 's/ /_/g'`. If you have a file called `A file.pdf`, your output will be

```
A file.pdf
A_file.pdf
```

and these you pass as arguments to `xargs`. However, `xargs` is instructed to take the first two arguments. In this case they will be `A` and `file.pdf`, neither of which exist, and therefore `mv` cannot stat them!

Here is, in my opinion, an easier way to do it:

```
for file in *.pdf; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/ /_/g')"; done
```

Comment: you can do without all the spurious `sed` processes

Comment: As @sehe points out, and as shown in [the answer by @Noctua](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23864321/3565972), you can forgo the use of `sed` by using Bash's own substitutions: `mv "$file" "${file// /_}"`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try quoting the filenames:

```
ls *.pdf | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/; p; s/ /_/g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

This is probably how you're doing it by hand, as well:

```
mv "File with spaces" "File_with_spaces"
```

Relying on pure bash, you'd have to use a for-loop and bash substitutions:

```
for file in $(ls *.pdf); do echo "$file" "${file// /_}"; done
```